# CSS: How to prevent Background colour to be overwritten by colour from less-file

Tags: css

I am working with this [page](http://www.frogn.kommune.no/info/kultur-idrett-fritid/info/lag-foreninger/).

The stylesheet-files and most of the design are written by another programmer.
In frogn.css the `background-color` is set that should be used for the outside area of the page (in which there is no information). E.g. like [here](http://www.frogn.kommune.no/info/kultur-idrett-fritid/info/).

In the page I am working with, the `background-color` is overwritten by the color from bootstrap.less
I prefer not to change the settings of the bootstrap-files, since it can affect other pages.

How do I enforce the `background-color` of frogn.css to be displayed ?
I tried using !important after the colour-attribute, but it didn't help.

**Update*:
I am noticing that setting !important after background-color actually worked. I did only a ordinary refresh, so I got the cached version of the page.

Comment: You given as `background-colour` or `background-color`? Bcos at some places you mentioned so.

Comment: In frogn.css :
body 
{ 
background-color: #eaeaea !important; 
color: #333; 
}

Comment: @RegisteredUser,
See this: http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in frogn.css i can see that the body background already has `!important`

```
body { background-color: #eaeaea !important; color: #333; }
```

and there's also a more specific rule applied:

```
#front { background-color: #EAEAEA !important; }
```

To overwrite these rules, you've to provide an even more specific selector, for example:

```
html #front { background-color: #FFF !important; }
```

this will be "heavier" and should overwrite the default values.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this did solve the problem:

```
body { background-color: #eaeaea !important; color: #333; }
```